# WordPress custom field images not getting inserted into array

Tags: custom-post-types, php, array

I am using Wordpress to create a dynamic gallery using Bootstrap. I created a new custom field and then set it to 'images' and then assigned it to my post type. It then shows up in my post, I uploaded my images into the field and then attempt to put all the attachments into an array and then i will loop through them to display.

```
$args = array(
'post-type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => 'any',
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
```

After doing this and doing a var dump with attachments, it says that nothing is in the array

Comment: `'post-type' => 'attachment'` should be `'post_type' => 'attachment'` (underscore)

Comment: God that's so stupid, works perfectly now. Is there anyway to accept your comment. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with native WordPress Uploader. If you assing your images to custom field you must use get_post_meta like functions. The basic way, Upload your images from **Add Media** area to your post and use this code in your `single.php` or which theme file you use.

```
if ($migallery = get_children(
    array(
            'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
            'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
        )
    )
)
{
            $aa_string .= "<div>"; //Before gallery div
            foreach ($migallery as $galerir)
            {
                $aath            = wp_get_attachment_image_src($galerir->ID, 'thumbnail');
                $aabg            = wp_get_attachment_image_src($galerir->ID, 'full');
                $aa_string      .= "<a href='$aabg[0]'>";
                $aa_string      .= "<img src='$aath[0]'/>";
                $aa_string      .= "</a>";
            }
            $aa_string .= "</div>"; //div ends
}
            $aa_string .= "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
            return aa_string;
```

You can change code (esp. foreach area)for Bootstrap gallery.

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work